# Is there a bijective correspondence between metric tensors and coordinate systems?

Tags: metric-spaces, coordinate-systems, tensors

Let's suppose I'm in a flat space described by cartesian coordinates, and that I define some new curvilinear coordinates by leaning on my cartesian coordinates. It is easy, at least in principle, to find metric tensor. I wonder if there is a bijective correspondence between coordinates systems and metric tensors, and if there is a way to jump from metric tensors to coordinates systems that generate them.

Comment: No. The standard metric $g(\vec u,\vec v)=u_1v_1+u_2v_2$ is the same after the coordinate system is rotated: $u_1'=u_1\cos\alpha+u_2\sin\alpha,\;u_2'=-u_1\sin\alpha+u_2\cos\alpha$.

Comment: Quite right. But it suggests another question. Perhaps there is a one-to-one correspondence between the metric tensors and the sets of transformations that differ only by a rotation of axes?